# How can I install knitr in Rhel8

Tags: r, knitr

Seeing below error while trying to install `knitr_1.2.tar.gz` This is on RHEL 8 and R version 3.4.3. Installing a old version of the package to satisfy user requirement.

```
R CMD INSTALL knitr_1.2.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/opt/R/3.4.3/lib/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘knitr’ ...
** package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘tidy.source’ is not exported by 'namespace:formatR'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/opt/R/3.4.3/lib/R/library/knitr’
```

Answer (score 0):

**knitr** 1.2 was released in 2013, and personally I strongly discourage your user from using such an old version. I'd like to know why they have to use it before trying to install it. If they must use it, this version of **knitr** requires `formatR::tidy.source` to be available, which in turn requires a very old version of **formatR** (before v1.0), because this function has been deprecated in **formatR** v1.0 and removed in v1.4. You may try to install **formatR** v0.10 before installing **knitr** v1.2. Again, strongly not recommended.